# Notepad ++ function tidy2

Tags: html, notepad++, tidy

I have a problem with **Tidy2**.

I wanted to '*tidy up*' my source code, that was okay but it makes an `&` to `amp;`. It advertise it.

Why and how can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the online [Tidy Documentation](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html) you will find how to set the ampersand settings:

> **quote-ampersand**
>   *Top Type*: Boolean 
>  
>   *Default*: yes 
>  
>   *Example*: y/n, yes/no, t/f, true/false, 1/0 
>  
>   This option specifies if Tidy should output unadorned & characters as & amp;

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the config file for Tidy2 (which is an option in the plugin menu).

To stop Tidy2 replacing all HTML entities (such as &), include the following line:

```
preserve-entities: 1
```

If you want to just change the ampersand handling, include

```
quote-ampersand: no
```